# Is there a way to make Visual Studio case sensitive on includes?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

Windows is case insensitive for files, but Linux is sensitive. It's really annoying when you develop on Linux and notice that the Windows team doesn't care about that.

Is there a way to force Visual Studio to be case sensitive on include files?

I've read about solutions doing a compilation after every commit in a Linux server and notifying the developer, but I can't do it. I need a way to force Visual Studio to be case sensitive so the Windows team can fix it while they're developing.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the compiler, the file system is case insensitive on Windows.  The typical way this is solved on Linux is to make every file name lower-case so you don't have to remember the casing.  That of course works fine on Windows as well.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Despite it having nothing to do with the compiler (or IDE), it _could_ be a compiler or IDE feature, a very useful one. Also, I've never heard of the always-lowercase convention on Linux. Furthermore, such convention would actually make more sense on Windows, because that's the OS which does not enforce correct casing on filename lookup. On Linux, you can safely agree on a casing-convention and be sure that miscasings are griped on by OS and compiler and IDE. A program that compiles fine on Linux w.r.t. filename-casing will compile on Windows, but _not_ necessarily vice versa.

Comment: The VS text editor acquired the ability to auto-complete #include names 3 years ago.

Comment: IMHO, code should not use case sensitively alone to distinguish  objects, file names, types, etc.

Comment: @chux, I suppose it is not so much about **relying** on case to distinguish objects, but more about not having code developped (and valid) on Windows breaking the builds on all case-sensitive environments. The idea of a potential warning for that at the compiler level makes a lot of sense imho.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Case sensitivity doesn't depend on the compiler, but the
underlying file system.  So Linux may not be case sensitive, if
the file system is remotely mounted on a Windows box, and vice
versa.  If you want to force case sensitivity on a Windows box,
the only solution I know is to remote mount a file system on
a Unix box.

Note that this shouldn't be a problem if you're developing on
Linux, then moving to Windows.  It's the reverse which is
a problem.  And the only real solution is to define and strictly
enforce a naming convention.  You need it for the code anyway
(since C++ is case sensitive regardless).  So if you have 
a class `FxTrade`, your coding conventions should insist that it
is `Fx`, and not `FX`; these convensions must be enforced in the
C++ code, or you'll go nuts having to look up each time which
one it is, and the same code review that enforces them in the
source should enforce them in the file names.

(And for what it's worth, it's a real pain to fix such an error
under Subversion, since `svn FXTrade.cpp FxTrade.cpp` doesn't
work under Windows; you have to move it to some other name, then
commit, and then move it to the name you want.)

Comment: Ok thanks. I was looking for a way to force Visual Studio to make the case sensitive check even though Windows is insensitive.Conventions are very useful if everybody follows them...

Comment: @PauGuillamon Don't I know it with regards to conventions.  My comments were largely drawn from personal experience, on a project where there was a good mix between `Fx` and `FX`, including in filenames, and cases where one file would include `FxTrade.h` and another `FXTrade.h`.  And I was one of the principals in porting it to Linux.  (The good thing was that the people responsible for the Windows builds agreed that such variations in names were a bad thing, and should be fixed, even when it worked on Windows.)

Comment: in April 2018, NTFS became [fully case-sensitive](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-ntfs-treat-folders-case-sensitive-windows-10) (on demand). It seems, though, that Visual Studio must be fixed to work with such folders correctly.

Comment: Actually, case sensitivity DOES depend on the compiler. As it turns out, Visual Studio converts the file name to upper case before passing it to the compiler. This led to some major headaches here; we only found the cause when we examined the `CL.command.1.tlog` file. It explicitly tries to compile `DLLMAIN.C` even when the .vcxproj files says `DllMain.c`.

Answer (score 13):

Since February 28, 2018 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/02/28/per-directory-case-sensitivity-and-wsl/ you can choose if a folder is case sensitive or not in windows.

```
fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo <path> enable
fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo <path> disable
```

the command does not work recursively if you want so you have to write something like that :

```
$directories = Get-ChildItem $path  -Recurse -Directory

ForEach($dir In $directories)
{
    fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo $dir.FullName enable
}
```

One liner:

```
$directories = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Directory ForEach($dir In $directories) { fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo $dir.FullName enable }
```